# Filter based on Data Validation drop down list

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a two part question that involves filtering a column based off of both data validation drop down lists, and dates.

1. The problem for me is to create a filter that will give me a subtotal based off both the **month** and the **expense/fixed asset** columns, then apply it to the subtotal cell **J25**.  Someone earlier had showed me how to do it by month, but I'm also interested in applying both filters.  I've looked through the function list, and can't seem to figure this out.

[image]

2. Afterwards, I'd like to take that subtotal and apply it into another sheet that contains cash flow information.  If I know how to do the above, I can probably figure this part out.  But I figure I might as well ask anyways.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I solved this problem with this function:

```
=sum(filter(J6:J25,K6:K25="Meals",month(B6:B27)=7))
```

This would give me the subtotal for all **Meal** expenses for the month of **July**.  This is a bit of a pain to apply when referencing this data in other sheets, but it works.